# How to write Portable C/C++/Objective-C++ code to target Apple iPhone/Mac OSX?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, macos, portability, objective-c++

I'm working with some C/C++ code that runs on Win32 and also VxWorks. It uses `#ifdef WIN32` to switch to platform specific implementations.

I've been using the code on the iPhone and I want to update it and keep it as portable as possible, but I'm not sure what's the best practice. So far I've been using `#ifdef __APPLE__` blocks.

**What should I be using to target Apple iPhone and Mac OS X?**

- Is `#ifdef __APPLE__` the best approach?
- Are there any gotchas to be aware of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might look at `__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED` to partition code for different versions of iOS. You might also look at partitioning [based on CPU](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Porting/Conceptual/PortingUnix/compiling/compiling.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002850-SW3), e.g. between 32- and 64-bit Intel apps.